# Can I use the slice method to return a list that excludes ranges in the middle of the original list?

Tags: python, list, range, slice

Is there a way to `slice` through a whole list while excluding a range of values or multiple range of values in the middle of the list?
For example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
print list[......] #some code inside
```

I'd like the above code to print the list while excluding a range of values so the output would be: `[1,2,3,8,9,0]` or excluding multiple value ranges so the output would be: `[1,2,6,7,0]` by using the slice notation or any other simple method you can suggest.

Comment: What's the criteria for the exclusion?

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name - it shadows the built-in function.

Comment: Seems pretty arbitrary. What's stopping you from going thru the list and just skipping the indices you aren't interested in?

Comment: @aqua Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @SukritKalra for the sake of the question, there isn't one. I'm just looking for some method of performing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> exclude = set(range(4, 8))
>>> [n for n in nums if n not in exclude]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 0]
```

Another example

```
>>> exclude = set(range(4, 8) + [1] + range(0, 2))
>>> [n for n in nums if n not in exclude]
[2, 3, 8, 9]
```

Comment: What if `nums = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]` or `nums = [2,7,4,9,8,3,1]` in other words what if the elements in the list were unordered or were strings?

Comment: Aaah it does, I didn't try it before and got thrown by the `set` function. So if I wished to exclude strings, I should create a separate list with the strings I want to exclude then pass that list in the `set()` function assigned to `exclude`. Or am I making that more complicated than it is?

Comment: You can concatenate the items you want to exlucde like in the second example `[1] + range(0, 2)` which works for list of strings and so on

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehensions:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> print [i for i in mylist if i not in xrange(4,8)]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 0]
```

Or if you want to exclude numbers in two different ranges:

```
>>> print [i for i in mylist if i not in xrange(4,8) and i not in xrange(1,3)]
[3, 8, 9, 0]
```

By the way, it's not good practice to name a list `list`. It is already a built-in function/type.

---

If the list was unordered and was a list of strings, you can use `map()` along with `sorted()`:

```
>>> mylist = ["2", "5", "3", "9", "7", "8", "1", "6", "4"]
>>> print [i for i in sorted(map(int,mylist)) if i not in xrange(4,8)]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]
```

Comment: The output you pasted is wrong, although the code is correct. :)

Comment: This is not exluding a range of indexes, it's excluding a list of avlues.

Comment: @SukritKalra Ah, sorry, that was some testing faults right there. Fixed :)

Comment: @Blubber Isn't that what he wanted? "I'd like the above code to print the list while excluding a range of values"

Comment: What if `mylist = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]` or `mylist = [2,7,4,9,8,3,1]` in other words what if the elements in the list were unordered or were strings?

Comment: This answer is not robust, what if the OP wants to specify multiple exclude lists, for different kinds of lists with different kinds of values throughout the code.

Comment: @InbarRose I've explained that in my code. OP can use `and` in the list comprehension, and I have also shown a use with `map()`

Comment: That is not robust. Adding additional "and"s or being able to map cast `str` to `int` is not a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a method, and an exclude list

```
def method(l, exclude):
    return [i for i in l if not any(i in x for x in exclude)]

r = method(range(100), [range(5,10), range(20,50)])
print r

>>> 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

---

My example uses ranges with ints. But this method can be any list of items, with any number of exclude lists with other items, as long as the items have an equals comparison.

---

Edit:
A much faster method:

```
def method2(l, exclude):
    ''' 
    l is a list of items, exclude is a list of items, or a list of a list of items
    exclude the items in exclude from the items in l and return them.
    '''
    if exclude and isinstance(exclude[0], (list, set)):
        x = set()
        map(x.add, [i for j in exclude for i in j])
    else:
        x = set(exclude)
    return [i for i in l if i not in x]
```

Comment: I like how your method allows for different ranges but what if the list `l = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]` or `l = [2,7,4,9,8,3,1]` in other words what if the elements in the list were unordered or were strings?

Comment: @Moolla The order of the list doesn't matter, nor the contents, as long as they can be compared to each other for equality.

Answer (score 1):

Given `my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`, in one line, with `enumerate()` and `range()` (or `xrange()` in Python 2.x):

```
[n for i, n in enumerate(my_list) if i not in range(3, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if using this was also valid:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
print my_list[:3] + my_list[7:]
```

Comment: That is a question and not an answer. Please use another wording to indicate a recommendation, which should also be substantiated

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Rephrase "Why not use?"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that takes multiple `slice` objects and gives you a list containing only the items included by those slices. You can exclude items by specifying around what you want to exclude.

```
from itertools import chain
def sliceAndDice(sequence, *slices):
    return list(chain(*[sequence[slice] for slice in slices]))
```

So, If you have the list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and you want to exclude the `4,5,6` in the middle, you could do this:

```
sliceAndDice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], slice(0,4), slice(7,None))
```

This would return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`.

It works with lists of things that aren't numbers: `sliceAndDice(['Amy','John','Matt','Joey','Melissa','Steve'], slice(0,2), slice(4,None))` will leave out `'Matt'` and `'Joey'`, resulting in `['Amy', 'John', 'Melissa', 'Steve']`

It won't work right if you pass in slices that are out of order or overlapping.

It also creates the whole list at once. A  better (but more complicated) solution would be to create a iterator class that iterates over only the the items you wish to include. The solution here is good enough for relatively short lists.